# How to remove tags from html using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have html code like this:

```
<div class="qtext">A financial model should be developed when the business planning process has reached the _______ planning stage</div>
<div class="rightanswer">The correct answer is: Operational</div>
<div class="qtext">Selling new products to existing customers is a strategy of</div>
<div class="rightanswer">The correct answer is: Product development</div>
<div class="qtext">In the strategic review and strategic planning process Product/Portfolio Analysis follows immediately after the</div>
<div class="rightanswer">The correct answer is: Industry and competitor analysis</div>
```

I tried removing div tags with this function:

```
def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
    print(cleantext)
```

and with this code:

```
cleantext = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, "html.parser").text
```

But the program returns:

```
caused error "expected string or bytes-like object"
```

Then how to remove the div tags?
I want the text in the format:

```
A financial model should be developed when the business planning process has reached the _______ planning stage
The correct answer is: Operational
```

Type of my raw_html is:

```
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please post the entire, relevant source code and stacktrace. The current issue is that `raw_html` is a `ResultSet` but `re.sub` and `BeautifulSoup` expect a "string or bytes-like object"

Answer (score 0):

To get text from `<div>` tags, use `.text` or `.get_text()`. For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="qtext">A financial model should be developed when the business planning process has reached the _______ planning stage</div>
<div class="rightanswer">The correct answer is: Operational</div>
<div class="qtext">Selling new products to existing customers is a strategy of</div>
<div class="rightanswer">The correct answer is: Product development</div>
<div class="qtext">In the strategic review and strategic planning process Product/Portfolio Analysis follows immediately after the</div>
<div class="rightanswer">The correct answer is: Industry and competitor analysis</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
raw_html = soup.select("div.qtext, div.rightanswer")  # <-- raw_html is ResultSet

s = "\n".join(div.get_text(strip=True) for div in raw_html)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
A financial model should be developed when the business planning process has reached the _______ planning stage
The correct answer is: Operational
Selling new products to existing customers is a strategy of
The correct answer is: Product development
In the strategic review and strategic planning process Product/Portfolio Analysis follows immediately after the
The correct answer is: Industry and competitor analysis
```